# basic component layout inheritance blazor

Tags: blazor

Let's say most of my components have a header. I want to create a base component that has the header variable and make all the other components inherit from that component and set the header. So I have

**BaseComponent**

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase;

<h1>@header</h1>

@Body

@code {

    protected string header;
}
```

**Component**

```
@inherits BaseComponent;

"internal component text"

@code {
  protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
         base.header = "Setting header for the parent"
    }
}
```

This compiles and shows up with no errors but the base header doesn't show up. It's like anything in the base doesn't get rendered. What am I doing wrong?

P.S.

I have also tried `@layout BaseComponent`, and even both directives at the same time.

Comment: To solve this you'll need to learn the Blazor Component Model and the mechanism of layout in Blazor. No Shortcuts...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2022 Update - This approach works fine for me in .NET 6.

Base Component:

```
<h1>@Header</h1>

@code{
    public string? Header {get; set;}
}
```

Derived Component:

```
@inherits BaseComponent

@code {
    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        base.Header = "New Header Value";
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer seems to not the question and is a code sample with no explanation.

Answer (score 37):

As of this writing, derived razor components implement all methods of their base classes automatically, including BuildRenderTree (which renders the HTML markup that you type within the razor file). When you type nothing, that method will make no attempt at calling the base BuildRenderTree method on its own. So you need to do it manually like so:

```
@inherits BaseComponent;

@{
    base.BuildRenderTree(__builder);
}

@code {
  protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
         base.header = "Setting header for the parent"
    }
}
```

Comment: where is the __builder coming from?

Comment: This answer needs updating - it's possible that blazor has moved on since; __builder does not exist

Comment: @JonBarker I just tried (Blazor 7) and it works.  However the IDE doesn't show it as working, but it actually builds successfully (and works)

Comment: Also works fine for me @JonBarker. I use it extensively.

Answer (score 19):

Expanding on @sw1337 answer, if the derived component has no markdown you can create it as a regular cs file rather than a razor file and it will work as expected without the need to call the base BuildRenderTree method. See this [github](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/21664) for more details.

## **Simple Example**

### ***Base Component (MyAbstractComponent.razor)***

```html
<h1>@header</h1>

@code {
    protected string header;
}
```

### ***Derived Component***

```cs
public class MyDerivedComponent : MyAbstractComponent
{
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
         header = "set header from derived component";
    }
}
```

---

## **Parameter Example**

### ***Base Component (MyAbstractComponent.razor)***

```cs
<h1>@Header</h1>

@code {
  [Parameter] public string Header { get; set; }
}
```

### ***Derived Component***

```cs
public class MyDerivedComponent : MyAbstractComponent
{
    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        // coalesce
        Header ??= "Default Header from derived Component"
    }
}
```

### **Usage 1 - Default Header From Derived Component**

***Some Razor File***

```html
<MyDerivedComponent></MyDerivedComponent>
```

***Result***

```html
<h1>Default Header from derived Component</h1>
```

### **Usage 2 - Specified Header From Derived Consumer**

***Some Razor File***

```html
<MyDerivedComponent Header="MyHeader"></MyDerivedComponent>
```

***Result***

```html
<h1>MyHeader</h1>
```

---

## **RenderFragment Parameter Example**

[Blazor Fiddle](https://blazorfiddle.com/s/2sbo50g4)

### ***MyBaseComponent.razor***

```cs
<h3>@Header</h3>

@if (ChildContent is not null)
{
    @ChildContent
}

@code {
    [Parameter] public string Header { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }
}
```

### ***MyDerivedComponent.cs***

```cs
public class MyDerivedComponent : MyBaseComponent
{
    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        // coalesce
        Header ??= "Derived Component Header";
        ChildContent ??= CreateDefaultChildContent();
    }
        
    private static RenderFragment CreateDefaultChildContent()
    {
        return builder =>
        {
            builder.OpenElement(0, "h4");
            builder.AddContent(1, "Derived Component default child content value");
            builder.CloseElement();
        };
    }
}
```

### ***Usage MyRazorPage.razor***

**Example One**
Consumer passes no parameters. Default values for `Header` and `ChildContent` from derived component are used.

*code*

```html
<MyDerivedComponent/>
```

*output*

```html
<h3>Derived Component Header</h3>
<h4>Derived Component default child content value</h4>
```

---

**Example Two**
Consumer passes `Header` parameter, default `ChildContent` of derived component is used.

*code*

```html
<MyDerivedComponent Header="Consumer Header"/>
```

*output*

```html
<h3>Consumer Header</h3>
<h4>Derived Component default child content value</h4>
```

---

**Example Three**
Consumer passes both `Header` and `ChildContent` parameters.

*code*

```html
<MyDerivedComponent Header="Consumer Header">
    <h4>Child Content - from consumer</h4> 
</MyDerivedComponent>
```

*output*

```html
<h3>Consumer Header</h3>
<h4>Child Content - from consumer</h4>
```

Answer (score 3):

The following worked for me:

The Razor compiler works quite simply in my eyes, in that it always overwrites a "BuildRenderTree" method. It does not matter whether it is derived from ComponentBase, IComponent or another type.
Since we cannot get the Razor compiler to generate a method name other than "BuildRenderTree" to include in our base class, we simply declare this method anew with the "new" keyword.

The only thing is that it requires an additional class in between that can redeclare the method signature.

**BaseComponentCore.razor**

```
<h1>@Header</h1>
@Body

@code
{
    protected virtual string Header => "Default";
    private protected virtual RenderFragment Body => null;
}
```

**BaseComponent.cs**

```
public abstract class BaseComponent : BaseComponentCore
{
    private protected sealed override RenderFragment Body => BuildRenderTree;

    // Allow content to be provided by a .razor file but without 
    // overriding the content of the base class
    protected new virtual void BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder builder)
    {
    }
}
```

**DerivedComponent.razor**

```
@inherits BaseComponent

<p>Hello world!</p>

@code
{
    protected override string Header => "Derived component";
}
```

**Result**

The result should be

```
<h1>Derived component</h1>
<p>Hello world!</p>
```

So internally ComponentBase still renders ComponentBase.BuildRenderTree (which is overriden in BaseComponentCore) while we can now integrate our new member BaseComponent.BuildRenderTree as a render fragment into the base class.

Answer (score -1):

It will never work in the way you're showing because setting a property on a parent component from an inner one doesn't trigger the rendering.
AFAIK the right approach to this problem is to have an independent service class that holds some common state (in your case, the current page title), and inject it on every component that needs to change it, by meaning of event actions:

That would be something like this:

```
public class GlobalUtilities
{
    public string MainPageTitle { get; private set; } = "Home (default value)";

    public event Action OnMainTitleChanged;

    public void SetMainTitle(string text)
    {
        MainPageTitle = text;
        OnMainTitleChanged.Invoke();
    }
}
```

Register it on the pipeline in Startup.cs:

```
services.AddScoped<GlobalUtilities>();
```

it should be registered as scoped, since it's lifetime is paired with the current connection.

And then use it on all the descendant components you need:

**Component**

```
//No need to inherit, only inject...
// @inherits BaseComponent;

@inject GlobalUtilities gu

<p>Something here</p>

@code {
    protected void OnInitialized()
    {
        gu.SetMainTitle("Whatever you want");
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Static content (I have some test words) of the parent is not showing up either though...it's like parent component doesn't exist.

Comment: There seems to be a misunderstanding of how inheritance works with this solution. When using the derived component it is "one" with all the features of both the base and its own implementation. The notion of triggering a change in the base component implies the objects as separate entities at runtime. The cause here is the BuildRenderTree method of the base component is being overridden by the derived component as it is a .razor file, it always implements the BuildRenderTree method when compiled so things will render otherwise the dev would have to implement every time.