# Blazor parent Component layout

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, razor, blazor

a component base has deffinition like

```
<div>Parent component</div>
@ChildContent
<div>Footer Parent component</div>

@Code {

[Parameter] public RenderFragment ChildContent{get;set;}

}
```

a child component is

```
@layout ParentComponent

<div>child component layout</div>
```

as result, rendered html is only child elements
and we see only

```
child component layout
```

I google it and find some result like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59990832/basic-component-layout-inheritance-blazor) that has result like this

```
child component layout
Panret component
child component layout
Footer Parent component
```

this means child component rendered two times!

this structure is work on 'page' like charm!!!
if I Add

```
@page "/ChildComponent"
```

to ChildComponent and navigate to it, it rendered correctly.
and this problem is only when we use it as component of a page

Answer (score 0):

Layouts using the `@layout` directive only work when the page is being directly accessed through navigation to the route defined with the `@page` directive. Layouts do not apply in component hierarchies.

If there’s a parent component that wants to embed a child component within some “layout”, then the child component either needs to contain that layout as well, or the parent component needs to explicitly add it.