# How to inheritance and override childContent component?

Tags: inheritance, blazor

I have two component

1. FormControl

   ```
   @*Form Control Component*@
   <div class=@WrapperClass>
       <label class=@LabelClass>@LabelText</label>

       @ChildContent
   </div>

   @code
   {
       [Parameter] public string WrapperClass { get; set; }
       [Parameter] public string LabelSize { get; set; } = CssHelpers.LabelFormSize();
       [Parameter] public string LabelClass { get; set; }
       [Parameter] public string LabelText { get; set; }
       [Parameter] public string ContentSize { get; set; } = CssHelpers.ColumnSize();
       [Parameter] public string ContentClass { get; set; }
       [Parameter] public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. FormControlValidation

   ```
   @*Form Control Validation Component*@
   <div class=@WrapperClass>
       <label class=@LabelClass>@LabelText</label>

       <div class="validation-message"></div>
       @ChildContent
   </div>

   @code
   {
       [Parameter] public string WrapperClass { get; set; }
       [Parameter] public string LabelSize { get; set; } = CssHelpers.LabelFormSize();
       [Parameter] public string LabelClass { get; set; }
       [Parameter] public string LabelText { get; set; }
       [Parameter] public string ContentSize { get; set; } = CssHelpers.ColumnSize();
       [Parameter] public string ContentClass { get; set; }
       [Parameter] public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }
   }
   ```

The only different between them is add more html to ChildContent. So how can i get that ?

Sorry about my english skill

I tried inherit from parent component and override ChildContent to add more content, but i don't know how to override ChildContent from child component

Comment: Looks like you have to inherit ComponentBase. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59990832/basic-component-layout-inheritance-blazor

Answer (score 0):

All Razor components/pages inherit from `ComponentBase` unless  you explicity set `@inherits`.

`ComponentBase` isn't designed to be used as a wrapper component, so you need to set out the full Razor markup in any child.

In your example

`FormControl` looks like this:

```
<div class=@WrapperClass>

    <label class=@LabelClass>@LabelText</label>

    @ChildContent

</div>

@code {
    [Parameter] public string WrapperClass { get; set; } = "col-12";
    [Parameter] public string LabelClass { get; set; } = "control-label";
    [Parameter] public string? LabelText { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment? ChildContent { get; set; }
}
```

And `FormControlValidation` looks like this.  We inherit the properties, but need to set out the markup in full.

```cs
@inherits FormControl
<div class=@WrapperClass>

    <label class=@LabelClass>@LabelText</label>

    <div class="validation-message">@this.ValidationMessage</div>

    @ChildContent
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter] public string? ValidationMessage { get; set; }
}
```

You could also write `FormControl` like this, using conditional formatting to add the valiudation message id one exists.

```
<div class=@WrapperClass>

    <label class=@LabelClass>@LabelText</label>

    @ChildContent

    <div class="validation-message">@this.ValidationMessage</div>

</div>

@code {
    [Parameter] public string WrapperClass { get; set; } = "col-12";
    [Parameter] public string LabelClass { get; set; } = "control-label";
    [Parameter] public string? LabelText { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment? ChildContent { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public string? ValidationMessage { get; set; }
}
```

Or write `FormControlValidation` like this where we pass in a `For` parameter and add a `ValidationMessage` component.

```cs
@using System.Linq.Expressions;
@inherits FormControl
@typeparam TValue

<div class=@WrapperClass>

    <label class=@LabelClass>@LabelText</label>

    @ChildContent

    @if (this.For is not null)
    {
        <ValidationMessage For=this.For />
    }

</div>

@code {
    [Parameter, EditorRequired] public Expression<Func<TValue>>? For { get; set; }
}
```

It looks like you are creating composite edit controls, so you can go even further.  Here's some demo code tht shows how to build a composite `InputNumber` based control.

```
@inherits InputNumber<TValue>
@typeparam TValue

<div class="col-12 mb-3">
    <label class="form-label">ID</label>
    @this.BaseContent
    <ValidationMessage For=this.ValueExpression />
</div>

@code {
    // Read only property to get the base component content
    private RenderFragment BaseContent => (builder) => base.BuildRenderTree(builder);
}
```

```cs
<EditForm Model=this.model OnValidSubmit=this.OnSubmit>
    <MyInputNumber class="form-control" @bind-Value=this.model.Id />
</EditForm>
```